# Email Alerts when Documents Uploaded including document

Tags: office-365

I'm using Office 365 and SharePoint and I basically need sharepoint to email a specific email address with a copy of a document when it is added to a folder on the site. Ideally, I don't want this email alert to come from a "noreply" email, but one we could assign to the site.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done out of the box.The build in Alerts will only send the metadata of the document. You would need to create an custom workflow to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spdactivities)

You can use "Send Email Extended" activities from SPDActivities available in CodePlex.

[image: Send Email Extended]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flow to send Email Attachments from Library or lists.
Check this link [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-email-with-attaching-file-from-SharePoint-library-document/td-p/87682).